# How does work conversion of virtual to physical address on x86_64 (levels, their names and attributes of pages)?

Tags: c, memory, x86, virtual-address-space, mmu

As we know, in 32- bit systems, there are 3 levels in the conversion of virtual to physical address :

- PD(10 bit): Page-Directory - where each entry (PDE) corresponds to needed Page-Table and defines the conversion for a range of 4 MB (for indicate to the PT, the highest 20 bits are taken from the PDE, and the remaining 12 are filled with 0)
- PT(10 bit): Page-Table - where each entry (PTE) corresponds to each page (4KB) in the virtual address space (for indicate to the Page, the highest 20 bits are taken from the PTE, and the remaining 12 are filled with 0)
- Offset ( 12 bit) - offset inside this page

Both the first 12 bits of the PDE and PTE, which is not used in addressing ( filled with zeroes ) have the following attributes:
[image]
[image]

But how does it look on 64-bit systems **x86_64**: how many levels, what are its called, what different from the 32-bit and what attributes are used?

Comment: Have you tried reading the software developers manual? It's explained there pretty extensively

Comment: @Leeor But, where can I find it with details such as in my question?

Comment: for e.g. - http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.pdf - vol 3A, chapter 4. It's cunningly named "paging" to avoid detection.